# Geospatial AI - Predictive models with TensorflowJS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am currently exploring ML for an application I'm working on and I'd would like to build a geospatial model using tensorflowJS.

As inputs I'd have lat & long for each location, along with other parameters such as type of location or type of business.

I want to build a predictive model that takes those inputs and can predict for example what type of business will eventually open and where they might potentially set shop.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? My main concern is to learn how to build a geospatial model with tensorflow JS with prediction capabilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its an interesting proposal; however, i don't think its just that straightforward. To predict potential shop locations, we will have to build a model in place that gets trained on existing data points (I feel GBM is a good fit for such use cases). I did a bit of research and found this paper has some useful information for your use case - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02839.pdf.

Wrt Tensorflow, the JS API is relatively new and i dont think it has all tensorflow goodness yet. However, wrt geospatial analysis using Tensorflow, you might find this link interesting - https://github.com/Qberto/ML_ObjectDetection_CAFO